# Primefaces: change selectionMode markup to use plain checkbox

Tags: checkbox, primefaces, datatable

I'm using PrimeFaces version 3.5 and using selectionMode like this:

```
<p:column selectionMode="multiple"/>
```

And it produces markup like this:

```
<div class="ui-chkbox ui-widget">
<div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
<input type="checkbox" name="x_checkbox">
</div>
<div class="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default">
<span class="ui-chkbox-icon ui-c"></span>
</div>
</div>
```

I'd like to have just the checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="x_checkbox">
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering, but i don't have enough reputation to comment.

Why do you want actually to have only the checkbox? Is it because of unselect even though you don't click in the checkbox, but anywhere in the column?

If so, I had the same problem, I did a little workaround, I set the width and height of the checkbox to the column width/height so you don't have to deal with that little "bug".

By the way, in primefaces 3.4 it was different as far as I know, they changed it due to a request from a primefaces Pro User.

Comment: The checkbox is visible like here: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionRadioCheckbox.jsf and it's a design issue that it has to be 'plain'. I can use CSS to expose the input checkbox but the markup that will be hidden anyway is a waste.

Comment: Yes, true. But as I said, they did it this way because a pf-PRO user requested it. Here is a forum post regarding this issue: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=28721&hilit=datatable+multiple+selection